# How to find a ppa for a given user?

Tags: apt, ppa

I've used lots of Launchpad pages that say "here's a ppa, you can add it to your sources with ...". But I find the structure of Launchpad confusing.

e.g. I'm interested in installing a ppa for Corebird from [Panda Jim](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+related-packages) but when I go to the user's page I can't see anywhere a ppa in the form that I could add to my sources.

Comment: The PPAs are listed in the "Uploaded to" column . Click on them and you will get instructions for how to add them. Is this what you are asking? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you click on the "Upload to" link you'll find the related PPA page.

Comment: Thanks! it was driving me crazy. It's not v obvs for a user, or at least this user IMHO!

Comment: @CelticWarrior that looks like an answer to me. Why not write it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Launchpad user's page you mentioned - [Panda Jim](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+related-packages) - you can find the "Upload to" column with several links. Clicking on each one takes you to the related PPA.